# calling webservice .net from outlook

Tags: c#, web-services

the End user (generally the approver) receives email (in outlook) with Approve and Reject Buttons. On clicking of These Buttons i want to call the respective web service methods in .NET to execute the business logic.

Can anyone help me out for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the email add the id of the thing that needs to be approved / rejected in the links in the email. The browser will open after clicking the link and your code will be triggered. Make sure though you force the user to be logged in and that he is authorized to approve / reject the thing that's being approved/rejected.